# How can I run docker container in existing network namespace?

Tags: linux, docker, network-namespace

I have an existing network namespace:

```
dewi@dewiserver:~$ ip netns list
dewinetns235 (id: 0)
```

How can I get a docker container to use and run inside this network namespace?
e.g. run something like

```
docker run --rm curlimages/curl:7.81.0 --namespace dewinetns235 -L -v https://curl.haxx.se
```

So in this instance I want the curl command to exist within the dewinetns235 network namespace

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick google turns up [this link](https://platform9.com/blog/container-namespaces-deep-dive-container-networking/). Looks like you attach the network namespace after running the container? I'm a bit surprised this isn't more built-in to Docker.

There is the `--network` [flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) to `docker run` but I suspect that's for Docker-created networks.